# Слияние таблиц в T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос, который объединяет две таблицы: продавцов и покупателей. На выходе получается имя продавца или покупателя, тип (продавец или покупатель) и страна. Как теперь можно оставить только те строчки, где какая-либо страна имеетcя и в продавце, и в покупателе? Т.е. если есть покупатели из России, а продавцов из России нет, то эти строчки нужно исключить.

Можно полностью изменить запрос, но не использовать `JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT CompanyName AS Person, 'Customer' AS Type, Country
FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT CompanyName AS Person, 'Seller' AS Type, Country
FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY Country, Person
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CompanyName AS Person, 'Customer' AS Type, Country
FROM Customers
where Country in (select distinct Country from Suppliers)
UNION
SELECT CompanyName AS Person, 'Seller' AS Type, Country
FROM Suppliers
where Country in (select distinct Country from Customers)
ORDER BY Country, Person
```